# How to organize the documents and write a cover letter for UK Visa?

Tags: visas, uk

I am a PhD student and will be visiting London in September, 2018 for presenting a research paper in a conference. My stay will be 9 days long and would like to roam around London during my stay there. My wife is going to accompany me during this visit. I have understood that I need to apply for a 6 months tourist visa. However, the following questions hit my mind everyday. Please help.

1. How to write the cover letter and is there any template available?
2. Since the application process is online, we both will apply separately. Will the interview process be taken together for both of us or separately?
3. If the interview will be taken together, should all the documents be produced with same cover letter or my wife's cover letter will be different?
4. Any other information, that I am missing but is most important during the application and interview process.

Since, I am applying for the first time and do not want to go through agent, I am asking the question here. Please help.

Comment: Does the application guidance state that a cover letter is mandatory? There is space at the end of the application itself to explain anything that’s not clear from the information you have to provide in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I know, you do not need any cover letter, because everything you are going to write in your cover letter are already mentioned in the online application, so you can answer it therein.

Yes, my common sense is telling me that you shall be filling up two separate applications for you and your spouse and the interview (if needed or held) it might be on the same day, but I am not sure if they are gonna interview you together, obviously they should interview you separately in order to know your genuine intentions in visiting the United Kingdom.

Finally, organizing documents, well, personally I am looking for this answer as well. Next monday is my appointment at Gerry's and I have no clue how to organize my documents, but I did arrange it in some order and make an index for it by putting together different documents in each different category like, personal, financial, proof of evidence, accommodation etc.

Answer (score 0):

Cover letter is not mandatory but it supports your application. If you have some extra information that is not being disclosed in the online form.
You must attach any document which you feel that it will support your application.
Like who is funding your visit.
They will organise but better you have seperate all by the heads e.g finance , accommodation etc